# MahApps.Metro ToggleSwitch Focus issues

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mahapps.metro

I am using the `ToggleSwitch` from `MahApps.Metro` as a `signoff` for my textbox. Basically, once the TextBox is valid, the ToggleSwitch will disable the TextBox. My TextBox has its UpdateSourceTrigger set to LostFocus because I am using a converter and need to wait until the user is finished to make sure it is completely valid. The ToggleSwitch has its UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged for the IsChecked property.

What is happening is when I type into my TextBox and then click the ToggleSwitch, my LostFocus never fires for my TextBox and my property is never set. I tested this out by changed the ToggleSwitch to a CheckBox and that fired my LostFocus and my property was set before the IsChecked property was updated. Any idea why the ToggleSwitch is not taking focus away from my TextBox?

Comment: Which version of MahApps do you have? If you have the latest stabel 1.1.2 then you should also test the latest alpha, which is also available from NuGet.

Comment: @punker76 latest version of 1.1.3 appears to be working for this. Thanks.  If you post an answer for this, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the latest alpha version of [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) (> v1.1.2) fixes this, which is also availabe via NuGet.